# How to dynamically set the URL of a img src attribute from axios service call in Vue JS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a requirement where I planned to dynamically set the URL on load of the component.
I have a  tag where the src attribute will be set from a service call which would return image. If the image is not present I need to set a fallback image. How can I handle this.

The image is in binary code format(.png) image

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. This is my solution :

1)For the image you set a dynamic src like this :

< img :src="image" >

2. In the data you set image to the url or relative path of the image you want to use as a default. Like this :

Data() {
return {
image  :  "path",
}
}

3. You preload the default image your main html file, like this :

< link rel="preload" type="image" or type="img/png" href="path" >

4. To change the image to the image in the axios call you just write :

this. image = messageImg

I hope this is helpfull.